# A way to view smart contract data without needing to connect wallet to dApp in ethersjs?

Tags: ethers.js, dapps, react, frontend

I am building a crowd-funding dApp using ethersjs to connect my smart contract to my front end, and I am looking to display public variables like total campaigns on my index page for style purposes.

Right now, I am calling a public variable `totalCampaigns` to get the returned number of total campaigns. The issue is, is I have to connect my wallet to view the number. If I don't, then no number is displayed.

In ethersjs, is there a way I can view public variables with getter functions, like my `totalCampaigns` variable without needing someone to connect their wallet? Or is it supposed to be connected by design and I should just scrap the idea all together?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible by creating a read-only contract instance.

First you need a provider, you can use a custom provider like Infura or Alchemy for example:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("https://Url-of-your-provider");
```

To create a read-only contract instance, you need to instantiate a contract with a`Provider` instead of a `Signer`. Here is an example with an ERC20 token.

```
const tokenContract = new ethers.Contract(tokenAddress, erc20ABI, provider);
```

Then you can call any function of your contract.

```
  const balance = await tokenContract.balanceOf("0xabc...");
  console.log('Balance:', balance.toString());
```

Comment: Sorry I should have added that I’m already doing all of that, yet still not able to view it without connecting

Comment: You don't need to connect any wallet if you manually set a provider. What is the error you encounter?

Comment: This is the provider I am using:
`export const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum);`

Should I alter this to another provider?

Comment: Okay so the issue was I was calling the Web3Provider and not the JsonRpcProvider with an Alchemy API key!